# Surprising behavior in multiple copy constructor inheritance

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, constructor, using-declaration

Starting with C++11, there can be two copy constructors, one taking a parameter of type `T&`, and one taking a parameter of type `const T&`.

I have a situation where (seemingly) **adding a second copy constructor causes neither one to get called**, when the constructors are inherited in a derived class. The copy constructor is overridden by a templatized constructor when both are present.

Here is a MWE:

```
struct A {
  template <typename... Args>
  A (Args&&... args)
  { std::cout << "non-default ctor called\n"; }

  A (A&) { std::cout << "copy ctor from non-const ref\n"; }
};

struct C :public A { using A::A; };

int main() {
  C c1;
  C c2(c1);
}
```

Running this code, we see output

```
non-default ctor called
copy ctor from non-const ref
```

which is as expected.

However, adding an additional constructor to `struct A` as follows:

```
  A (const A&) { }
```

somehow causes the other copy constructor not to get called, so the output becomes

```
non-default ctor called
non-default ctor called
```

In my use case, I want to inherit all the constructors from a base class into a derived class, including the copy constructors and anything else. But it seems that somehow the two copy constructors don't get inherited when they are both present. What is going on here?

Comment: What compiler / flags? After adding `A (const A&) { }`, I only see one line of output: https://wandbox.org/permlink/ex8AyRHqF1ChsNcc (the const ref version is being called)

Comment: Not sure, but latest gcc and clang will both call the const-ref version on [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/)

Comment: @Arcinde Thanks for the link to wandbox! It seems that the behavior is as I described until gcc 7 (I was using gcc 5.4). So I guess it was a bug in the compiler? Or is it unspecified behavior?

Comment: @super It looks like the behavior changed as of GCC 7 and clang 4.0. I'm still not sure whether this was a bug (in both compilers) or unspecified behavior.

Comment: It was always possible to have `A(A&)` and `A(A const&)`

Comment: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e0281d9388e114c1) showing both expected and unexpected result depending of version of compiler.

Comment: @M.M My note about having multiple copy constructors being somehow new in C++11 is based on the documentation [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor). I think you could always have both constructors but only since C++11 are they both considered to be copy constructors.

Comment: @DanRoche I assume the section you refer to is supposed to indicate that `= default;` was added in C++11. You could still have the two user-provided copy constructors in C++03. In fact section 12.8/2  of the C++03 standard has an example of exactly that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration

> If one of the inherited constructors of Base happens to have the signature that matches a copy/move constructor of the Derived, it does not prevent implicit generation of Derived copy/move constructor (which then hides the inherited version, similar to using operator=).

So

```
struct C :public A { using A::A; };
```

is

```
struct C :public A
{
    using A::A;
    C(const C&) = default;
    C(C&&) = default;
};
```

where `C(const C&) = default;` is similar to

```
C(const C& c) : A(static_cast<const A&>(c)) {}
```

So with

```
struct A {
  template <typename... Args>
  A (Args&&... args)
  { std::cout << "non-default ctor called\n"; }

  A (A&) { std::cout << "copy ctor from non-const ref\n"; }
};
```

template constructor is chosen, but

```
struct A {
  template <typename... Args>
  A (Args&&... args)
  { std::cout << "non-default ctor called\n"; }

  A (const A&) { std::cout << "copy ctor from const ref\n"; }
  A (A&) { std::cout << "copy ctor from non-const ref\n"; }
};
```

`A (const A&)` is chosen.

As you can notice, there is also a defect:

> The semantics of inheriting constructors were retroactively changed by a defect report against C++11. Previously, an inheriting constructor declaration caused a set of synthesized constructor declarations to be injected into the derived class, which caused redundant argument copies/moves, had problematic interactions with some forms of SFINAE, and in some cases can be unimplementable on major ABIs. Older compilers may still implement the previous semantics.

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0136r1.html

With that defect, your class C would be

```
struct C :public A
{
    using A::A;

    template <typename ...Ts>
    C(Ts&&... ts) : A(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...) {} // Inherited.

    C(const C&) = default;
    C(C&&) = default;
};
```

So you call `C(C& c) : A(c) {}` (after template substitution).

Comment: Thanks for the useful link from the docs. But the behavior is exactly the opposite of what you have here - the template constructor is chosen only in the **second** case, when both ctors are present. (It seems this was maybe a compiler bug that has been fixed in more recent versions?)

Comment: @DanRoche: There is also a defect. so old compilers might still implement that.